# What's the lifetime of memory pointed to typeinfo::name()?

Tags: c++, rtti, typeid, typeinfo

In C++ I can use `typeid` operator to retrieve the name of any polymorphic class:

```
const char* name = typeid( CMyClass ).name();
```

How long will the string pointed to by the returned `const char*` pointer available to my program?

Comment: It is linked into the executable image.  Look at the .map file.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As long as the class with rtti exists. So if you deal with single executable - forever.
But for classes in a Dynamic Link Librariy it shifts a little. Potentially you can unload it.

Comment: +1 Most accurate answer, though you need to fix that first sentence, I know what you're trying to say, but it just seems like gibberish

Answer (score 3):

The memory returned by `type_info::name()` will be available for the application's lifetime.

Comment: Is this guaranteed by the Standard?  I know that the result of `typeid()` has application lifetime but I can't find anything that places a lifetime on the result of `type_info::name()`.

Comment: TTBOMK, it is with the caveat given by Dewfy. However, since the standard doesn't even acknowledge the existence of dynamic libraries...