# Will multiple calls to typeid(T).name() return the same pointer?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, rtti, typeid, typeinfo

In C++ I can use `typeid` operator to retrieve the name of any polymorphic class:

```
const char* name = typeid( CMyClass ).name();
```

The string pointed to by the returned `const char*` [will be available to my program for as long as the corresponding class exists](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2109648/57428).

Will multiple calls of `typeid(T).name()` return the same pointer value for the same `class T` or are they allowed to return different pointers?

Comment: You're asking the wrong question.  Not "are they allowed to return different pointers?", but "are they required to return the same pointer?"  In C++, anything is allowed unless it would violate the specified behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No they are not required to return the same pointer.

I have also seen in the wild system that do not.
Each DLL had its own copy of the type object that contained the nmae thus calling the typeid(N).name in shared lib A and shared lib B will result in a different pointer (Though the same underlying string).

Answer (score 2):

Probably, but why rely on that rather than the actual type info if you want to do comparisons?

Comment: To be more precise, you can put `const std::type_info*` objects into a set or use them as keys on a map. You should provide a custom comparer, although on some platforms comparing the pointers is just fine.

Answer (score 2):

The standard doesn't say. And BTW, the lifetime of the type_info returned by typeid is to the end of the program.

Comment: @unapersson: If the class is in a DLL and that DLL is unloaded `type_info` becomes unavailable as well.

Comment: @sharptooth That's not what the C++ standard says.

Comment: @sharptooth: "The result of a typeid expression is an lvalue of static type const std::type_info ... The lifetime of the object referred to by
the lvalue extends to the end of the program." §5.2.8.1 of N3290.

Comment: @Mat, @unapersson: The standard also says that objects with static lifetime are destroyed when the program exits.  Yet objects with static lifetime within a DLL are destroyed when the DLL unloads.  You can't infer the behavior of a system using DLLs based on a standard that isn't aware of them (the addition of DLLs does make the implementation non-compliant).

Comment: In a sense, a DLL is a "program". I have a hard time believing that type_info objects somehow can outlive its host DLL.

Comment: @Ben I wasn't inferring anything, just stating what the standard says, or in this case doesn't say.

Comment: The standard does not cover OS specific features. But I bet this falls under implementation defined behavior. The long and short is that objects from DLL A can hold onto the type Info object from DLL A but not DLL B. If DLL A is unloaded then you better not have any objects(including type info) defined in A still loose in your system as it is likely to go boom.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say that this is implementation defined. The standard (based on N3290) has this about the `std::type_info` class (§18.7.1):

```
const char* name() const noexcept;

Returns: An implementation-deﬁned NTBS.
```

There is no wording that I can find requiring equality of these pointers for `type_info` objects describing the same type.

Comment: The requirement is that the type_info objects themselves should compare equal for the same type. The strings can contain anything the implementation pleases, like "X" for all types.